# How would one say "To reach their potential"

Tags: grammaire, traduction, vocabulaire

Wondering how one would say a phrase such as "he can help them reach their potential"

would you use "à atteindre leur potentiel"

Thanks!

Comment: You can also use *réaliser son plein potentiel*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the most evident word in French (potentiel) the word "maximum" would have to be used.

- Il peut les aider à atteindre leur maximum.

> (harrap's) **to reach one's potential** → atteindre son maximum

Other possibilities can be used.

- Il peut les aider à donner toute leur mesure.  (Robert-Collins: **He hasn't realized yet his full potential.** → Il n'a pas encore donné toute sa mesure.)
- Il peut les aider à faire de leur mieux.
- Il peut les aider à réaliser le meilleur de ce dont ils sont capables.

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: Could you please explain why "potentiel" wouldn't be suitable here? I see no reason...

Comment: @LaurentS. I think it wouldn't be idiomatic. One reason for that is that I don't feel it is (the idea of realizing one's potential somehow is not  put that way in French), which is of course not enough for having a certitude, but another reason is that two dictionaries do not use "potentiel"; why would they reject the term if it had some currency in this context?

Comment: @LaurentS. Il me semble que c'est un anglicisme récent; voir par exemple [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/r%C3%A9aliser-son-potentiel.3278222/).

Comment: If I look at [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/potentiel), I find "Ensemble des ressources que possède en puissance un individu ou un groupe humain ou un système industriel; capacité d'action ou de production." which seems to correspond to the current situation? While I couldn't be sure if it's not an anglicism, it is certainly very idiomatic, there are plenty of articles online about "Développer son potentiel", "Réaliser votre plein potentiel", etc...

Comment: @LaurentS. The  concept "potentiel" is close to the English "potential", but how can you speak of realizing something **you have** or  of **developing** it? In this sense I understand the remark made in Wordreference: rather, it is a matter of **using** that potential. I think the English "potential" does not take into account exactly what is materially available but what can be achieved through what is materially  available (intelligence for instance).